# Draw specific polynomial with given roots by reading roots from txt file

Tags: plotting, functions, polynomials, procedural-programming, drawing

i am new to mathimathica and i just can do basic things with it. i have a file.txt that contains roots of two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$. both polynomials have the same degre and first n numbers are roots of p and next n numbers are roots of q , now i have thousands of $(p,q)$ roots in file.txt how can i read roots from file.txt and plot $p(x)-q(x)$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$.

for example if degre is 2 and have 2 $(p,q)$ roots, and i have 1 2 3 4 5  6  7 8 in file i want first plot $(x-1)(x-2)-(x-3)(x-4)$ and then $(x-5)(x-6)-(x-7)(x-8)$.

at the moment i only write Plot instruction manually and copy data one by one which is not good.
i would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on the structure of "file.txt", but perhaps this will work as a starting point. I created a test file called "test.txt" which contains a single number on each row with the numbers 1 through 8.

```
numCurves = 2; (* The total number of curves to plot *)
numPolys = 2; (* The total number of polynomials i.e. just p(x) and q(x) for now *)
degree = 2; (* The degree of each polynomial *)
data = Import["~/Desktop/test.txt", "Data"];
array = ArrayReshape[
   data, {numCurves, numPolys, degree}];
temp = Subtract @@@ Apply[Times, x - array, {2}]
Plot[temp, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Plot of 2 polynomials.]

This assumes that you know the number of p/q datasets in the file. If you don't know that beforehand, you can do a quick calculation using the `Dimensions` of `data`.

Basically, I import the text file and then reshape it into a form that has `numCurves` rows, `numPolys` columns (always 2 if you're just doing p(x) - q(x)), and `degree` elements in each of the 2 columns.

```
data
array
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 3 \\
 4 \\
 5 \\
 6 \\
 7 \\
 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{1,2\} & \{3,4\} \\
 \{5,6\} & \{7,8\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

We can see what happens when we do `x - array`:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{x-1,x-2\} & \{x-3,x-4\} \\
 \{x-5,x-6\} & \{x-7,x-8\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

I'm using `Apply[Times, x - array, {2}]` so that it multiplies all the `x - _` parts within a single column together, but I don't want anything else getting multiplied. The curly brackets around the 2 tell it I *only* want it to apply at level 2 of my array.

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 (x-2) (x-1) & (x-4) (x-3) \\
 (x-6) (x-5) & (x-8) (x-7) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

So now the format of my array is basically:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p_1(x) & q_1(x) \\
 p_2(x) & q_2(x) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

so I can use `Subtract @@@ Apply[Times, x - array, {2}]` to get my final set of polynomials:

$\{(x-2) (x-1)-(x-4) (x-3),(x-6) (x-5)-(x-8) (x-7)\}$

The `@@@` symbol is shorthand for `Apply[___, ___, {1}]`. Finally, since there's just a list of polynomials, you can call `Plot` with that list.

If your data is in a slightly different format (like there are multiple numbers on each row), the initial steps with reshaping might be slightly different.

Comment: thank you very much , the format of file.txt is  like this  , we know number of $(p,q)$ roots , we know their   degre (they are equal) , for example if we have 3 $(p,q)$ roots , and if their degre  is 4 for example , we will have 24 roots in total , first 4 roots for p1 ,  next  4 roots for q1 and we draw  p1-q1 , then the next 4 roots for p2 and next 4 roots for  q2 again draw p2-q2 and so on. also is it possible to  draw each  graph separately? i do not want draw lots of functions in one image. i hope my explanation clear things more , sorry if it is not good enough.

Comment: @wiliammercer Sure, drawing them separately is easy and there are a number of options. `Plot[#, {x, -1, 1}]&/@temp`, Table[Plot[temp[[i]], {x, -1, 1}], {i, 1, Length@temp}]`, `Map[Plot[#, {x, -1, 1}]&, temp]`, etc. I think my code above follows the format you specified, I just wasn't sure if each row of the text file had a single number on it or if it had all of the p roots or all of the p and all of the q roots.

Comment: absolutely perfect , thank you very much.